# How to apply color gradient in listplot based on the density of points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of points ( a list with sub lists which are {x,y} coordinates. I would like to have a listplot where the areas with higher density of points are in darker colors and areas with lower density of points have lighter colors so it is visually visible that in some areas points might overlap each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
points = Join[
   RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{-0.5, 0.25}, 0.07*IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    1000],
   RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{0.6, -0.1}, 0.03*IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    1000],
   RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {1000, 2}]
   ];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[points];
ListPlot[points, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[PDF[skd, {x, y}]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: points density hue]

Comment: You could also use `GrayLevel[1 - PDF[skd, {x, y}]]` for a monochromatic gradient. Or you could use `Darker@Hue[...]` instead.

Comment: Thank  you for your help. I was wondering how did you decided  to use SmoothKernelDistribution ?

Comment: Pjana the PDF of a `SmoothKernelDistribution` is the estimated probability density of the points. When the points are more densely compacted one would expect a higher probability density, and when they are more sparse, a lower probability density. You could visualize it with `DensityPlot[PDF[skd, {x, y}],{x,-1.5,1.5},{y,-1.5,1.5}]`

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Comment: Do you know how can I add a legend to this type of listplot?